# PropertyInfo to Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, reflection

I want to create a kind of WebGrid 2.0 for ASP.NET and Razor.

Defining a ModelClass (TData) the WebGrid should create the HTML for the table on its own.

The Properties of TData should be read via reflection (typeof(TData).GetProperties). The attributes of the properties should define some css and html styling or even some data (DisplayNameAttribute => ColumnHeader).

Now I came to the point, when I want to call htmlHelper.DisplayFor(...propertyInfoToExpression...) to render the datas content.

How could I call DisplayFor, when I only got the data(row)/model and the propertyInfo?

---

WebGrid-Class:

```
public class TableModel<TData>{

     private readonly IList<TData> _rows;
     private readonly IList<TableColumn<TData>> _columns = new List<TableColumn<TData>>();


     public TableModel(IList<TData> rows) {
        _rows = rows;

        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(TData).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in propertyInfos) {
            if (!Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(NoColumnAttribute))) {
                _columns.Add(new TableColumn<TData>(property));
            }
        }

    }

    private MvcHtmlString GetCellHtml(HtmlHelper<TData> helper, TableColumn column, TData dataRow){

         TagBuilder cellTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("td");
         cellTagBuilder.InnerHtml = helper.DisplayFor(...propertyInfoToExpression...)

    }

    public MvcHtmlString ToHtml(HtmlHelper helper){
         TagBuilder tableTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("table");
         TagBuilder headTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("thead");
         TagBuilder bodyTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("tbody");

         ...
         return new MvcHtmlString(tableTagBuilder);
    }
}
```

Sample Class for TData just to catch the idea:

```
public class UserModel{

      [NoColumnAttribute]
      public int Id{get;set;}

      [CssClass("name")]
      public string Firstname {get;set;}

      [CssClass("name")]
      public string Lastname{get;set;}

      [CssClass("mail")]
      public string Mail{get;set;}

      [CssClass("phone")]
      public string Phone{get;set;}

}
```

Comment: what? can you describe it with sample code ( for mode, as well as snippet of desired call structure). might be easy to figure out a solution then. usually with an expression you can solve things without having to deal with PropertyInfo.

Comment: I added some sample code.

Comment: I don't think your class concept is right yet? I suppose you want to call it like this (assuming the model you pass to your view is of type UserModel: @Html.WebGridFor(x => x)? Making a list of it would be pointless then.

I suppose you're open to heavily modified code of yours?

Comment: Nice hint. Thanks. But the problem with displayfor() remains, doesn't it?

Comment: For now yes. I'll have a look at it. I'm waiting for someone else to finish something either way. Might take a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried...

```
private MvcHtmlString GetCellHtml(HtmlHelper<TData> helper, TableColumn column, TData dataRow){

     TagBuilder cellTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("td");
     cellTagBuilder.InnerHtml = helper.Display(column.PropertyInfo.Name, dataRow);
     ...
}
```

...?

If you need `DisplayFor` only for your method `GetCellHtml` then you don't really need to build an expression from a PropertyInfo.

Comment: To be honest: I didn't really get the sense of the display-method. But I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried it and got it working. I didn't need the dataRow because the helper defines the data in its model. the parameter for display would be additional viewinfo.

Final-Solution: 
public MvcHtmlString GetHtml(HtmlHelper<TData> helper) {
            return helper.Display(PropertyInfo.Name);
        }

Answer (score 2):

You could try it like this:

```
        var properties = typeof (TModel).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties)
        {
            ParameterExpression p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "m");
            ParameterExpression p2 = Expression.Parameter(info.PropertyType, "m."+info.Name);
            Expression<Func<TModel, dynamic>> exResult = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, dynamic>>(p1, p2);

            helper.DisplayFor(exResult);
        }
```

Sorry that it took a while. Had to do some other work.

Comment: I had to change the order of p1 and p2 to get the expression working. Unfortunatly the displayfor methode displays all properties and not only the one defined by the expression. Nevertheless I gave you an upvote.

Comment: ok then. glad you got it working anyway. If you're still using reflection though you should have a look into compiled expression performance vs reflection + GetValue. The performance difference is huge. So for that matter using expressions might help you out later on.